# Sought solace Vs sought for solace

Tags: grammar

I see the above two phrases used interchangeably.

Google n-gram viewer prefers "sought solace".

Are they both correct?

Comment: Can you give some example sentences that you wonder about?

Comment: @ artfullyContrived: I don't know where you got that *used interchangeably* idea from. I just Googled ["sought for solace"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22sought+for+solace%22&oq=%22sought+for+solace%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.15167328j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). The top result is this actual question, followed by a page seeking parents to sign up for a program called "Solace for the Children". The next 6 results are all duplicates of the same barely-literate blog page from 2006, followed by a couple of book citations from the early 1800s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Seek* (p.p. *sought*) means **attempt to find**, and that phrase can be directly substituted. *Find* does not take *for*.

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/seek) doesn't make any mention of *for* — the formatting of that entry is a bit complex to reproduce here — but it does include the synonym ***ask for/look for***, which is where any confusion might arise.

> ask for (something) from someone: "he sought help from the police"

However all their examples which use *seek* do not have any particle or preposition. *Seek* does not take *for*.